# Python 3 turn range to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

I'm trying to make a list with numbers `1-1000` in it. Obviously this would be annoying to write/read, so I'm attempting to make a list with a range in it. In Python 2 it seems that:

```
some_list = range(1,1000)
```

would have worked, but in Python 3 the range is similar to the `xrange` of Python 2?

Can anyone provide some insight into this?

Comment: also, `some_list[i] == i+1`, so you probably don't really need a list anyway.

Comment: @RikPoggi. for example, one might need to supply a list for a plotting function.  Sometimes a range will suffice, but a range cannot be concatenated (is immutable), so if you need to add a default starting value to all lists being plotted, that on needs to be turned into a list also.

Comment: Essentially any reasonable approach for copying a list, will equally well accept the range as an input and produce the corresponding list as an output. Well, except for slicing-based approaches, since those will just give another `range`.

Answer (score 343):

You can just construct a list from the range object:

```
my_list = list(range(1, 1001))
```

This is how you do it with generators in python2.x as well.  Typically speaking, you probably don't need a list though since you can come by the value of `my_list[i]` more efficiently (`i + 1`), and if you just need to iterate over it, you can just fall back on `range`.

Also note that on python2.x, `xrange` is still indexable<sup>1</sup>.  This means that `range` on python3.x also has the same property<sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>`print xrange(30)[12]` works for python2.x</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>The analogous statement to <sup>1</sup> in python3.x is `print(range(30)[12])` and that works also.</sup>

Comment: I would say "construct" or "build" (or possibly "materialise")- as you're not "converting" (as such) a generator to a list, you're creating a new list object from a data source which happens to be a generator... (but s'pose just splitting hairs and not 100% sure what I favour anyway)

Comment: My +1 for "construct" as it is consistent with other OO languages. The `list(arg)` is understood in other languages as calling a constructor of the `list` class. Actually, it is also the Python case. The debates whether the object is filled during the construction (as in the C++ case) or only during the first automatically called method (as in the Python `__init__()` method) cannot change the basic abstract idea. My view is that *the list constructor takes the iterator and fills the list with the returned values*.

Comment: @pepr -- Yeah, I agree.  construct is probably the best word to use.  One word of caution.  It is not guaranteed that `__init__` is called.  (from the documentation of `__new__` { http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__ } ) "If __new__() does not return an instance of cls, then the new instance’s __init__() method will not be invoked."

Comment: Why does it give an error in jupyter notebook and working fine in shell? Error: `'range' object is not callable`

Comment: How could I add `np.nan` into this list?

Comment: @subtleseeker: It works fine in a notebook. You probably assigned something to `list` or `range`.

Answer (score 54):

In Pythons <= 3.4 you can, as others suggested, use `list(range(10))` in order to make a list out of a range (In general, any iterable).

Another alternative, introduced in Python `3.5` with its unpacking generalizations, is by using `*` in a list literal `[]`:

```
>>> r = range(10)
>>> l = [*r]
>>> print(l)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Though this is equivalent to `list(r)`, it's literal syntax and the fact that no function call is involved does let it execute faster. It's also less characters, if you need to code golf :-)

Comment: To be clear, you can still one-line it: `[*range(10)]` works just fine for when you don't need the `range` for any purpose but initializing the `list`. Side-note: My favorite(okay, not really) part of the unpacking generalizations is that empty `set`s now have a literal syntax, `{*()}`, or as I call it, the one-eyed monkey operator. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger that's how I originally thought about writing it. I decided to be a bit more verbose in order to not confuse new Python users :-)

Answer (score 26):

in Python 3.x, the `range()` function got its own type. so in this case you must use iterator

`list(range(1000))`

Comment: "in this case you must use iterator"? What the heck is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I am using python 3.7 & tried x=list(range(1000)) but got the error TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @Earthshaker You must have a typo, like `list(range(1000))()`

Answer (score 21):

You really shouldn't need to use the numbers 1-1000 in a list. But if for some reason you really do need these numbers, then you could do:

```
[i for i in range(1, 1001)]
```

List Comprehension in a nutshell:

The above list comprehension translates to:

```
nums = []
for i in range(1, 1001):
    nums.append(i)
```

This is just the list comprehension syntax, though from 2.x. I know that this will work in python 3, but am not sure if there is an upgraded syntax as well

Range starts inclusive of the first parameter; but ends Up To, **Not Including** the second Parameter (when supplied 2 parameters; if the first parameter is left off, it'll start at '0')

```
range(start, end+1)
[start, start+1, .., end]
```

Comment: Why comprehension? Just: `list(range(1000))`

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining why it's i for i in... instead of simply for i in?

Comment: I haven't worked with python3. So I'm not fully certain about how it works. I know comprehensions will work, but wasn't 100% on the casting. But if casting works, then you're right and your way is more pythonic.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: It's not "casting", it's calling the [`list()` constructor with an iterable](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list). The `list()` constructor knows how to create a new list when given any iterable object.

Comment: The way list comprehensions usually work is: [doSomethingWith(i) for i in someList], because if you aren't doing something with i (such as taking one of its fields, as in [i.someField for i in someList], or using a method), doing a list comprehension is redundant.  Therefore, the syntax for list comprehensions is as you see.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: `list(range(1000))` will work in python3 just like `list(xrange(1000))` in python2

Comment: range(1000) will return values [0, 1, 2, .. 999] .  OP needs range(1,1001) to get a list of [1, 2, 3, .. 1000].  Updating post to reflect this.

Comment: list comprehension is more generalizable

Answer (score 20):

The reason why Python3 lacks a function for directly getting a ranged list is because the original Python3 designer was quite novice in Python2. He only considered the use of `range()` function in a for loop, thus, the list should never need to be expanded. In fact, very often we do need to use the `range()` function to produce a list and pass into a function.

Therefore, in this case, Python3 is less convenient as compared to Python2 because:

- In Python2, we have `xrange()` and `range()`;
- In Python3, we have `range()` and `list(range())`

Nonetheless, you can still use list expansion in this way:

```
[*range(N)]
```

Comment: The whole *point* is to make it less convenient to make a `list`, because that's usually the wrong thing to do. For 99 out of 100 use cases, making an actual `list` is inefficient and pointless, since `range` itself acts like an immutable sequence in almost every way, sometimes more efficiently to boot (e.g. containment tests for `int`s are `O(1)`, vs. `O(n)` for `list`s). In Python 2, people tended to use `range` by default, even though `xrange` was almost always the better option; in Python 3, you can to explicitly opt in to the `list`, not get it by accident by using the wrong name.

Comment: The comment about the Python 3 designer and his expertise in Python 2 is quite bold and impertinent.

Comment: @kazarey But is it true?  There are a lot of things in python that are questionable along these lines

Comment: Wasn't Guido the designer of python3? I cannot find anything to the contrary.

Answer (score 13):

Python 3:

```
my_list = [*range(1001)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you want 1-1000 (inclusive), use the `range(...)` function with parameters 1 and 1001: `range(1, 1001)`, because the `range(start, end)` function goes from start to (end-1), inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) in Python 3.

Here is a example function that return in between numbers from two numbers

```
def get_between_numbers(a, b):
    """
    This function will return in between numbers from two numbers.
    :param a:
    :param b:
    :return:
    """
    x = []
    if b < a:
        x.extend(range(b, a))
        x.append(a)
    else:
        x.extend(range(a, b))
        x.append(b)

    return x
```

> Result

```
print(get_between_numbers(5, 9))
print(get_between_numbers(9, 5))

[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question...?