# python 3 list from range

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, range

According to [list from range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480042/python-3-turn-range-to-a-list)

the following should work:

```
x = list(range(0, 10, 100))
print(x)
```

but it prints `[0]`, while I am expecting `[0,0.01,...,10]` What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range` doesn't do fractions. Also the third argument is the step, that is:

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

To get what you want with fractions you can use `numpy` arrays. For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
```