# Executing a kmedoids python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, k-means

I'm trying to run the `kmedoids` clustering implementation available on this [github page](https://github.com/letiantian/kmedoids).

The provided [minimal working example](https://github.com/letiantian/kmedoids/blob/master/example.py) is pretty straightforward, yet I can't manage to execute the first line using the `kMedoids()` function without raising an error:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
import numpy as np    
import kmedoids

# 3 points in dataset
data = np.array([[1,1], 
                [2,2], 
                [10,10]])

# distance matrix
D = pairwise_distances(data, metric='euclidean')

# split into 2 clusters
M, C = kmedoids.kMedoids(D, 2)  # <-- THIS RAISES AN ERROR

print('medoids:')
for point_idx in M:
    print( data[point_idx] )

print('')
print('clustering result:')
for label in C:
    for point_idx in C[label]:
        print('label {0}:　{1}'.format(label, data[point_idx]))
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 9, in kMedoids
File "mtrand.pyx", line 4832, in mtrand.RandomState.shuffle
File "mtrand.pyx", line 4835, in mtrand.RandomState.shuffle
TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment
```

I set up the example in Eclipse PyDev as follows for Python 3.5:

- Installed all modules using `pip3 install` (numpy, scipy and scikit-learn)
- Added the `kmedoids.py` file in the same directory as `example.py`

Has anyone tried using this function recently? Could my version of Python (3.5) be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issues, indeed certainly related to the `kMedoids()` [code](https://github.com/letiantian/kmedoids/blob/master/kmedoids.py) which wasn't intended initially for Python 3.

To make it work for Python 3.5, edit the following lines related to the `range()` function as follows (cf. this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480070/3976696)):

```
index_shuf = range(len(rs)) -->  index_shuf = list(range(len(rs)))
```

and

```
for t in xrange(tmax): --> for t in range(tmax):
```