# Interpolate standard function python, func(10,16,2) -> [10 12 14 16]

Tags: python, list, function, interpolation, standards

I am looking for a function in Python, which I have used before, which takes three arguments. Let's say `x` and `y`, and `stepsize`. Then it will generate a list starting at `x`, taking steps of size `stepsize` and ending at `y`.

Example would be:

```
listIwant = function(20,30,2)
print(listIwant)
```

And then it would print:

```
[20 22 24 26 28 30]
```

Can't seem to find the function I am looking for.

Comment: You are looking for `range`. But the end is non-inclusive, so it would be `range(20, 31, 2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 turn range to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480042/python-3-turn-range-to-a-list)

Comment: np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1) is the function I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `range`, which returns a list in Python 2, but in Python 3 returns a generator. However this is easily converted to a list:

```
print(list(range(20,30,2)))
>>> [20, 22, 24, 26, 28]
```

Note: the second argument is a non-inclusive upper bound, so in order to get your desired output you would need to feed it:

```
print(list(range(20,31,2)))
>>> [20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]
```

Comment: Thanks, any alternative to this function for floats?

Comment: @Dennis can you be a bit more explicit? i.e. give me an example of expected input and output?

Comment: @Dennis I don't think there's a built-in, but it wouldn't be too hard to make your own with the `yield` keyword. Try defining a function that yields a few values (like `return`, but the code carries on) and test it in a for loop.

Comment: np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)  is the function I was looking for.

Comment: @Dennis **note:** [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) returns an ndarray, not a list.