# How to get a list using the range function?

Tags: python, list, range

How to get expected answer `[0, 1, 2, 3]` using the `range` function?

I tried this Python code:

```
print(range(4)),
```

result:

```
range(0,4)
```

The result is different from online playgrounds:

```
result 01: range(0,4) 
result 02: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: and what is the question for answer `[0, 1, 2, 3]` ?

Comment: try using list function in your range() ```print list(range(4))```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 turn range to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480042/python-3-turn-range-to-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do `list(range(4))`.

The `range()` function returns a generator (only produces one value at a time). You have to convert that generator to a list.

Comment: [Note on range object not being a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092267/if-range-is-a-generator-in-python-3-3-why-can-i-not-call-next-on-a-range) but the answer is generally correct.  Just an alert since there can be confusion in attempts to use range as a generator (i.e. no next).

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax of `range` function:

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

`start` : Numerical index, at which position to start(optional)

`stop` : Index you go upto but not include the number(position to end)(required)

`step`: Incremental step size(optional)

**Examples**

```
x = range(0, 6)
for n in x:
  print(n) //output: 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

In your case you need a `list` containing the integers so as @Green Cloak Guy said you should use `list(range(4))`