# Python Evens in the interval

Tags: python

Evens in the interval
Print all even integers from the interval [a, b] in decreasing order.

```
Input example #1
2 7
Output example #1
6 4 2
```

here is my code:

```
a,b = map(int,input().split())
for i in reversed(range(a,b,2)):
   print(i,end=" ")
```

how can i do this without reversed?

Comment: range(b, a, -2)

Comment: dos not work for input  "3 11" , "7 1", crashes for inputs that are not int-convertible or have more/less then exactly 2 ints, does not check the "even" condition of the task, does not work with bigger number put in first, but overall a start.

Comment: Remember you also need to handle the case where the start value is odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that b is even with `b//2*2` and use `range` in reverse order:

```
list(range(b//2*2,a-1,-2))
```

output: `[6, 4, 2]`

But, honestly, if this is a nice learning example, for practical uses, go with `reversed` this will be more efficient (and explicit)

full code:

```
a,b = map(int,input().split())
for i in range(b//2*2,a-1,-2):
   print(i,end=" ")
```

For fun, here is a loop-less version:

```
print(' '.join(map(str, range(b//2*2,a-1,-2))))
```

Comment: i dont understand why we do this (b//2*2 )

Comment: @Samir have you tested this bit of code? It floors b to the lowest even. For this it does an integer division by 2 and multiplies by 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your range into an array. [Post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480042/python-3-turn-range-to-a-list)
And then print them backward with [::-1]

```
a,b = map(int,input().split())
print([*range(a,b,2)][::-1])
```