# Showing range of numbers

Tags: python

I need to generate the list of integers 1 to 100 (that's ok). But I need to then show a list of the first 10 numbers

```
print(" ")
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(list[i])
print(" ")
```

This is giving me `list[1]`, then next line `list[2]` etc., instead of List `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Comment: What did you _expect_ `list[i]` to do?

Comment: Where is `list` defined? Do you instead want to [`slice`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 turn range to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480042/python-3-turn-range-to-a-list)

Answer (score 3):

If you want only first ten numbers of `list`, do in this way:

```
list = [i for i in range(1,101)]
print(list[:10])
```

But if you want the list to be in multiples of 10 numbers using a loop, try in this way:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(list[10*i:10*(i+1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing inside of a loop so it prints out something every time it runs. Don't know if it would work, just a thought, but maybe try appending to list in the loop then print the list outside, line4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
print(" ")
yourList = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    yourList.append(i)
print(" ")

print(yourList)
```