# I tried creating a List comprehension in Python but I am getting a None result

Tags: python

This is my Python code

```
numbers = []

for i in range(20):
    numbers.append(i)

print(numbers)
```

This is my list comprehension

```
numbers = [numbers.append(i) for i in range(50)]
print(numbers)
```

The result I am getting is None, None, None, ...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Use `numbers = [i for i in range(50)]` instead of `numbers = [numbers.append(i) for i in range(50)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a slight misunderstanding about what list comprehension is or should be used for.

If you just want a list of consecutive numbers, `numbers = list(range(20))` does the trick.

But let's assume you want something more special. Then what you *should* write is something like

```py
numbers = [i for i in range(50)]
```

What happens in your case is that for 50 times you call `append(i)` on `numbers`. That `append` method does indeed append the number to the list, but it doesn't *return* anything. And because it doesn't return anything, you're just collecting 50 times `None` in your example...

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `None` because that is the return value of `.append()`.

You don't need `.append()` anyway.  Use this instead:

```
numbers = [i for i in range(50)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```py
numbers = [*range(50)]
```

as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64764669/9475509)

Comment: @john-gordon and @cadolphs already explain where `None` comes from. I just put shorter way to produce list from range but actually without list comprehension.